# Calling a function in a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the object of a jquery plug in I'm making use of. I want to eventually be able to add features to the plugin to suit my needs. I am currently having a problem with calling one the functions I defined in the plug in. Here is the skeleton of the code I have:

```
;(function($) {
      $.fn.myPlugin = function(o) {
                    .//Implementations here
                    .
                    .
            var Ex =  function(e){
                    //implementations here
            };

      }; 

})(jQuery);
```

The reason I want this function inside is because I want access to some of the variables defined. I would like be able to call function Ex from my html file but whatever I tried so far hasn't worked. An example of what I have tried is:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.Ex("x");
```

No return statement anywhere. I'm not great at javascript or jquery but I'm trying to learn. Any help in explaining what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin design pattern is wrong.

To achieve what you want, you can use this common one :

```
;(function($){
  var methods = {
     init: function() {
       //stuff
     },
     function1: function() {
       //stuff
     },
     function2: function(opt) {
       //stuff
     }
  };
  $.fn.myPlugin= function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } 
  };
})(jQuery);
```

With this structure :

`$.fn.myPlugin();` will call `init()`

`$.fn.myPlugin("function1");` will call `function1()`

`$.fn.myPlugin("function2",option_exemple);` will call `function2(opt)`

Disclaimer : I use this very often, but it's not mine. Can't remember where I found it*.

- edit : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring , thanks to Beetroot-Beetroot for the reminder !

Comment: I didn't design the plugin. I am making use of one online. Restructuring it might cause a problem

Comment: Well, hard to tell without having a look to the plugin itself, but you could maybe `return`the variables you need.

Comment: the plug in is online, it's called Basic-Slider if it helps

Comment: how? I tried returning this which would the slider object but it didn't

Comment: Add `return $slider` (or `$wrapper` depending on which you want) to the end, just after `init()`, you can then chain the plugin : `$('#banner-fade').bjqs(opt).css('background','red')` per example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20781/discussion-between-mddw-and-k-ken)

Comment: mddw's pattern is the one advocated [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). It is well worth learning and using.